# How would I combine BiPredicate and Predicate?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I have two lambda functions (predicates):

```
final Predicate<Node> isElement = node -> node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
final BiPredicate<Node, String> hasName = (node, name) -> node.getNodeName().equals(name);
```

Which I want to combine in some concise way, something like this:

```
// Pseudocode
isElement.and(hasName("tag")) // type of Predicate
```

and then pass to another lambda function:

```
final BiFunction<Node, Predicate<Node>, List<Node>> getChilds = (node, cond) -> {
    List<Node> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node tmp = nodeList.item(i);
        if (cond.test(tmp)) {
            resultList.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
};
```

As a result I'm expecting it would look like the following:

```
List<Node> listNode = getChilds.apply(document, isElement.and(hasName("tag")));
```

But `and` method of `Predicate` doesn't accept `BiPredicate` parameter.

**How I could do this?**

Answer (score 6):

Stop rewriting every method into a lambda expression. There is no real benefit. If you have an ordinary method, you can call it by its simple name without having to append `apply`, `test` or similar. If you really need a function then, you can still create a static method reference using the `::` operator.

So if you want to improve you code, think about using the new *API* instead of overusing the Java language features. For example:

```
static List<Node> getChilds(Node node, Predicate<Node> cond) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    return IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength()).mapToObj(nodeList::item)
                    .filter(cond).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Regarding you attempt to combine `Predicate`s. Of course, you *can* express everything as a function without compromise. For example:

```
Predicate<Node> isElement = node -> node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
Function<Node, String> nodeName = Node::getNodeName;
Predicate<Node> both = isElement.and(nodeName.andThen("tag"::equals)::apply);
```

but is this really an improvement?

You may simply write

```
Predicate<Node> both = isElement.and(n -> n.getNodeName().equals("tag"));
```

or, even simpler, since `Node`s not representing `ELEMENT` nodes will never report a node name of `"tag"` you don't need the first predicate at all and the entire operation becomes:

```
getChilds(document, n -> "tag".equals(n.getNodeName()));
```

That might not feel as fancy as complicated function composition, but it's a *practical* solution.

Answer (score 5):

You need to write a static helper function that [curries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) your BiPredicate down to a Predicate which you can then `.and()` with the other predicate.

`isElement.and(curryRight(hasName, "tag"))`

alternatively, you can just do this:

`isElement.and(node -> hasName.test(node, "tag"))`

it's not that much longer

Comment: Thanks. But this looks like inconsistency. When sometimes I use `isElement.and(Predicate2).and(Predicate3)`, and from time to time have to reinvent carrying functions for overall combination of `Predicate`, `BiPredicate`, `MorePredicate`, .... Especially if we take into account that `carry()` have to be implemented as method, not a function. And for lambda calling syntax will looks like `carry.method()`. Thus we get some awful `isElement.and(curry.apply(hasName, "tag"))` or `isElement.and(Helper.curry(hasName, "tag"))`.

Comment: *"Especially if we take into account that carry() have to be implemented as method"*. static imports are your friend.

Comment: Could you point out how curryRight should be implemented in my case?

Comment: static method + generics. it's just two lines, i'm sure you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: I think it's not so simple as you suggested. If I want `carry` as lambda expression (don't pollute namespace with functios/classes which just are used one time in all application) this would looks like this:
`final TriFunction<BiPredicate<Node>, Node, String, Predicate<Node>> carry = (biPred, node, name) -> { (node) -> biPred.test(node, string) }`. But `TriFunction` is not implemeted in `java.util.function` and should be implemented by yourself.

Comment: And if we decide to write `carry` as a method, the `lambda-expressions` approach in this case is getting meaningless, because we can implement all functions as helper methods, not using lambda at all.

Comment: @likern: and what’s wrong with that? It’s not clear why you are trying to write everything as a lambda expression.

Comment: @likern, if you find java insufficiently functional for your needs you could look into other JVM languages like scala or clojure. or for a library providing some commonly used higher order functions if you don't want to write your own.

Answer (score 3):

Change the lambada function `hasName` to a function `hasName(String name)` returns lambda function.

```
final Predicate<Node> hasName(String name) { return node -> node.getNodeName().equals(name); }
```

Then your code below will work.

```
List<Node> listNode = getChilds.apply(document, isElement.and(hasName("tag")));
```